# Java Request password to sign with certificate

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

We are creating an applet so users from a site can sign a document with the certificates installed in their browser.

Problem is that we would like to request the user to introduce the "password" of the certificate for a higher level of security. Certificates installed in browser are all p12 files correctly imported (with password already introduced as the normal process requires).

when we run this code

```
Java.Security.KeyStore key2 = obtainCertificates();
Java.Security.PrivateKey key = (Java.Security.PrivateKey) key2.getKey(alias,password.toCharArray());
System.out.println("PK is " + key);
System.out.println("alias " + alias);
if (key == null || key.equals("") || key.equals(" ")) {
    System.out.println("Password is wrong");
    return "CLAVEINCORRECTA";
}
```

It works no matter the value for "password" is....

How can we make the system to check if the password introduced matches with the password of the certificate loaded in the browser?

This is something we know it can be done with KeyStore.load()... but we dont want the user to point us where the file of the certificate is... we just want to use the certificates installed in the browser.

Comment: Did you try > Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
String encodedKey = new Base64Encoder().encode(key.getEncoded());

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have reviewed your proposal and I think what you are suggesting is to check the PrivateKey. Getting the privatekey it is not a problem,  We want to get a certificate from the browser and then request the password of the certificate to the user (variable "password"), to make sure the user can use this certificate to sign the document. We are able to get the privatekey of the certificate, but with the function getKey, it does not matter what password you introduce, it always works. How can we do to ask the user to introduce a password and check if it matches with the certificate?.